# Hypernym for "movie" and "TV series"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

What is the hypernym for *movie* and *TV series*?
I read that *medium* might be possible, but it doesn't sound that good.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you're asking about. Are _movie_ and _series_ the same thing here? Would examples be _Harry Potter_, _Star Wars_, and _Pirates of the Caribbean_? Or do you by "movies" mean films such as _The Polar Express_, where "series" refers to a television series, like _The Big Bang Theory_? Also, you might want to check out our companion site for [ell.SE], where this may have been a better fit.

Comment: @I edited my question. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: It is clearer now, and as a result, I think you'll get better answers now, too. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Movies vs series is an industrial segregation. Movies that form a series are called sequels. A prequel is a member of a sequel.

Comment: Film industry? Broadcasting media? The world of entertainment? Show business/showbiz? Light entertainment?

Comment: video entertainment, video media

Comment: I can't post an answer for some reason, but I use "Production", which makes sense, as both tv shows and movies have producers

Answer (score 12):

Extending on Pam's answer, **Show** is considered the lowest common hypernym for TV program and Movie.

This can be backed up with reference to the [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) lexical database. 
See several papers including:

- [Miller, G. A. WordNet: a lexical database for English, *Communications of the ACM, ACM, **1995**, 38, 39-41*](http://mooo.cf/20140731/Reference/1995%20-%20Miller%20-%20WordNet%20a%20lexical%20database%20for%20English.pdf)
- [Miller, G. A. Nouns in WordNet: a lexical inheritance system International journal of Lexicography, *Oxford Univ Press, **1990**, 3, 245-264*](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/245.full.pdf)

The definition of the show synset in question (`show.n.03`) is:

> 'a social event involving a public performance or entertainment'

Which is quiet far from the base words, but according to the lexigraphers that constructed (/and continue to construct) WordNet, as good as we can get.

---

For interest of others, one can make such queries against wornet in python via NLTK:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
wn.synset("television_program.n.01").lowest_common_hypernyms(wn.synset("movie.n.01"))

#Or equivalently (because NLTK integrates Morphy):
wn.synsets("TV_show",wn.NOUN)[0].lowest_common_hypernyms(wn.synsets("movie",wn.NOUN)[0])
```

---

Its also possible to query WordNet online,
though I don't know of a good way to get lowest common hypernym:

- [Movie](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=movie&i=4&h=100000#c)
- [TV show](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=tv%20show&i=5&h=1011000#c)

---

The short of the matter is, if we are willing to trust WordNet as an authoritative source (which thousands of peer reviewed publications have), then we can be confidant that Show is the lowest common hypernym.

Comment: but in the context of media - let's say someone is trying to name a media drive, it is not ideal since "Show" also refers to concerts. Also it sounds strange to call a movie a show.

Answer (score 8):

How about a *show*? Is it too broad?

Comment: I have never seen an answer made up with two questions!

Comment: Hmm... could you call Harry Potter a show?

Comment: @Davlog - to be fair, this answer was posted **before** you made your edit, so it wasn't entirely clear what you are asking about. Moreover, there are some local dialects that commonly use the word _show_ as a synonym for "movie." NOAD defines show as *a public entertainment, in particular, a play or other stage performance, esp. a musical, or a program on television or radio*. That definition wouldn't preclude _show_ from your list of candidates.

Comment: Dear Astuto, the reason why I sometimes pose my "answers" in a humble rethorical interrogative fashion is that I am non-native speaker/learner, so I wish to leave space for my proposal to be debated and corrected if necessary

Comment: Pam, that is fine, but *all* answers on this site are subject to debate and correction. No need to specifically mark them up as such. An answer must be presented as an answer, and not as a  question in its own right.

Comment: In American English, *show* can refer to a television program, a stage production, or a particular showing of a movie (e.g. *the matinee show*, *the 10pm show*)— but not for a film itself, except as an affectation, as in using the old-fashioned term *picture show*. Moreover, I've never heard of anyone mixing media; if asked to list my favorite *shows*, I cannot simply answer "*Top Gear* [TV], *Into the Woods* [stage musical], and *The Lion in Winter* [film]"; I would need to ask first what is meant by *show*.

Comment: @choster - I've heard places where _show_ can be used for the film itself (e.g., "We went to the movies last night?" "Oh, what show did you see?") I've only heard that in the upper midwest, though; for the most part, I'd agree with you – it's far from universal AmE.

Comment: @J.R. You're right; I have heard *show* used that way on the coasts as well. But I think the principle that *show* can only refer to one medium at a time still applies. "Let's go out and see a show tonight." "There's an Ibsen festival playing at the PAC." "Oh, I was thinking *Hot Tub Time Machine*, not a *show* show."

Answer (score -4):

I would go with media, since it's a plural for medium.

Comment: Since there are so many media  -  movies, TV series, newspapers, magazines, radio, etc.  -  it would be hard to find a single word that covers just two of them,

Comment: What about the software installer section of my media library? `Media` is about the broadest you can get. It could even represent a piece of paper my neighbor slipped under my door.