# Hypernym for "film" and "TV series"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I'm a software engineer and I need to write a class that will hold code common to a `Film` class and a `Series` class. I need to name this class with a hypernym for both.

For the moment, the solution we have found is `AudioVisualEntity`, but we are not very happy with it. Is there a better term?

To help clarify things, here are the properties this class will hold :

- `originalTitle`
- `title`
- `audioLanguages`
- `countries`
- `colorType`
- `images`
- `videos`
- `synopsis`
- `productionYear`
- `shortSynopsis`
- `releaseDates`
- `contentClassification`
- `averageRating`
- `genres`
- `themes`
- `budget`
- `catchPhrase`
- `altId`
- `slug`

Here is what the Film class adds:

- `type` : `FilmType`(long or short film)
- `duration`

Here is what the Series class adds:

- `type` : SeriesType
- `seasons`
- `episodes`

Comment: What common features of those two is your software dealing with? I'd likely choose differently depending on those.

Comment: I updated my answer with the class properties

Comment: Does 'series' refer to a single year of or all years of a tv show?

Comment: @Neil: all years. A `Series` has many `Episode`s and many `Season`s

Comment: Related: [Hypernym for “movie” and “TV series”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127196/hypernym-for-movie-and-tv-series)

Comment: I want to add _movie_ also. Based on its definition, it is a hypernym but it is used for film.

Comment: Great question. This is a problem we have regularly when discussing things over on [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com). As you can see from our site name, we have no good solution yet. ;)

Comment: Does it refer to 1. the abstract thing (the movie or show "themselves") or 2. a broadcast of one of those things or 3. the physical thing (a movie DVD or TV series box, say)? I would assume it's option 1?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you could do a lot worse than using the [BBC Programmes Ontology](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/po) as the basis for your class design.

Comment: @HenrikN : you're right, it's 1.

Comment: @tobyink : nice, but it won't fit our model, which is VoD-oriented. Still, there are good things we could find there, so, thanks!

Comment: @greg0ire not sure that film and series should share a common class, they are different concepts

Comment: @JamesRyan, In your model, maybe, in ours, look at all the fields they have in common!

Comment: @greg0ire it is what they don't have in common that counts

Comment: well, I can add the fields that are specific to each one, you'll see there's not much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply call it a *production*. [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/production) says:

> A work produced for the stage, screen, television, or radio.

Comment: We've modified it a bit and chosen `VideoProduction`. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

As a general EL&U question, I would suggest *title*. For your purposes having a *Title* class, table, struct or whatever that also has a *Title* field of a different type will probably be a great nuisance.

For that reason, I'd lean towards *Release*, or perhaps *Product*. This latter is probably too wide a hypernym for many uses, but if these are the only sorts of products you have, and the most reasonable extensions you can foresee would not introduce *completely* different products, then it might serve well in this context.

Comment: Product will probably be used as the name of another class, so `Release` or `VideoRelease` is what I would lean towards too.

Answer (score 10):

I would probably call it a `release`.

Comment: Good option, but a `VideoRelease` might be more exact

Comment: actually, since there is a `releaseDates` property, this proablbay won't be a good fit for my particular case. Might work otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

In Utah (and presumably elsewhere in the Far West), we have a slang catchall, simply:

**Show**

"Yeah, Game of Thrones is a great show!"

"Oh, I saw Inglorious Basterds the other day. Have you seen that show!"

People from California find it annoying, but it's technically accurate! It's also short and simple.

Comment: As a counterpoint, I'm from the Midwest and "What was the last show you saw in a theater?" would be a confusing question, I wouldn't think to answer it with a movie title. I'd probably think of a play or something. Likewise, "what's your favorite show?" would never result in me answering with a movie title.

Answer (score 5):

The term "motion pictures" covers both film and TV.

Comment: Technically, I suppose that's true, but I've always regarded a "motion picture" to be a cinematic release, not a television show.

Comment: @J.r.: And nowadays we have "internet videos," so we really need the hypernym.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to describe motion pictures and television with a single word, look no further than the name of the union of actors who perform in both media: the "Screen Actors' Guild".

"**Screen**" means "Movie" + "TV" (+ Netflix, etc.)

Comment: This is great!  Next time I want to see a film I'll ask my friends "Want to go watch a screen?"

Comment: Maybe Screen something would do the trick, but Screen all by itself does not work. So, Screen Show maybe ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an indirect quality –not the main one–  shared by the two things. For example if both were stocked in the same format:

> "MPEGs" "MP4s"

the same way you'd use "MP3s" if you were grouping together podcasts, audiobooks & songs.

Also,

> Fictions or Video fiction

if it's what's commun between them.

You can use also the generic "[video files](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/video#related-to-more)","video items", "video media", "video records" the same way you'd talk about audio files/audio items/audio media/audio record.

Comment: fiction looks good, but there will also be documentaries, so I'm afraid it's not generic enough.

Comment: I'm not sure why you appended all those words to _video_: files, items, media, fiction, etc. What's wrong with simply, _video_? That was the first thought that sprang to my mind: `video ISA film | series`.

Comment: because in a computer context, video or audio could be the settings for video, could be a video or audio  player, could bethe collection of video file, could a list of video ports...As Op example was Audiovisualentity, I thought he wanted something specific.

Answer (score 3):

How about *screenplay*

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenplay):

*A screenplay or script is a written work by screenwriters for a film, video game, or television program.*

Or if to narrow

*Screen Production*

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to be particularly post-modern you could call it a 'videotext'.

Comment: This comes off as alient to me... "I'm seeking happymood making, provide videotext admission, theaterperson."

Comment: Videotext, somewhat strangely, is an academic way of saying it, though. To that crowd, everything is a text.